# Structuring go project for this use case

Tags: go, design-patterns, struct

I am building a Go service that communicates with multiple third-party providers. This go-service acts as an interface between these multiple providers and my internal applications consume just one API from this Go service.

My application has the below structure now

```
- app
- config
- controllers
- dto 
- exceptions
- providers - All external API calls to thrid-party happens here
- services - Business logic
- tests
```

I would have to integrate to over 10 third-party APIs and I am confused on how to keep the structs for JSON marshal and unmarshalling.

From a maintenance perspective, I keep few things in mind for restructuring the application

- each third party services can be integrated by a developer independently without getting into one another messing someone else's code. The developer may only necessarily know the integration of his/her third party integration.
- Each third-party might have some common utils which can be utilized, say for eg: authentication mechanism or logging or things like sentry.
- Where do I place the structs of request and response of all external API call?

**What I was planning was**

- dto

  - thirdparty1RequestStruct
  - thirdparty1ResponseStruct
  - thirdparty2RequestStruct
  - thirdparty2ResponseStruct
    ... and so on.

But when I have around 20 third parties APIs, there would be a lot of request-response struct and the directory will be too big from a readability perspective.

My question is

```
How would you as a go developer go about structuring the application keeping the above requirements in mind?
```

Please bear with this question as I am pretty new to go programming. Understand that this is opinionated, but for this specific use case how does it work? I couldn't find any resources online.

Comment: You may want to look how [caddy](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy) designs its [architecture](https://caddyserver.com/docs/architecture) for support of (a lot of) third party modules (which is actually just APIs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what @Muhamed Keta writes, I would add the suggestion of using sub-packages for each of the providers instead of one mega-package with 10s of providers in it. This would look like this:

```sh
/cmd/app
/config
...
/lib # or /utils 
/providers
    /provider1
        dtos.go
        client.go
        ...
    /provider2
        dtos.go
        client.go
        ...
```

In go, the package name becomes a namespace and a non-optional identifier/discriminator for client code to use. In this way you avoid having to write longer, redundant and sometimes stuttering names to differentiate from provider to provider:

So in code using your providers instead of writing `providers.Provider1Client` you'd have `provider1.Client`. This seems to be a common go pattern/best practice.

This also means that all code that relates closely to the implementation of each provider lives in close proximity, preventing name collisions and aiding developers that focus on a provider exclusively.

I've added a `lib` (or alternatively `utils`) package that would contain generic code that may be shared among many providers.

This is subjective, but hopefully I've outlined some reasonable pros given the language's constraints.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that this question is opinionated to an extent, and there is no right answer for this.

Personally I like having an `cmd/app`, `config` sub-directories as they contain the logic of starting/running the app and I feel lie nicely when bundled like that.

For the rest of the app I like having a flat structure, going into sub-directories only if there's heavy coupling. It's important to have a separation of the layer between the handler, database (if there is one), and external APIs (if there are some).

I would suggest something like:

```
/cmd/app
/config
/provider
  provider1.go // contains the request response structs in itself
  provider2.go // contains the request response structs in itself
provider.go
```

In the end more code might look less maintainable but it is better then heavy coupled code. If one API suddenly decides to switch the payload format, it is much easier to find the whole process in one of the files instead of scouring through 3 in very different subdirs.